# How to place a logo in the simpleslides module in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, presentations, logos, modules

I found `simpleslides` module extremely suitable for academic presentations, yet I am clueless as how to place a logo in the lower right area of the slides in any of the specified styles. Is there any way to place a logo simply from the presentation context file? or something must be done in the third party module styles? The documentation of simpleslides module indicate that tweaking any of the provided styles is possible, but still your help would be highly appreciated to show how. I didn't find helpful information by searching the [ConTeXt Wiki](https://www.contextgarden.net/Main_Page)

**MWE from the same module**

```
\usemodule[visualcounter]
\usemodule[simpleslides][style=Sunrise] 
\setupTitle
  [ title={Simple Slides?},
   author={Hirwanto},
     date={6 Januari 2013},
  ]



\setupvisualcounter
  [simpleslides:squarescounter]
  [
   distance={(\the\dimexpr\visualcounterparameter{maxwidth})/last_counter - width},
  ]

\stopmode
\starttext

\placeTitle

\SlideTitle {The first slide}

Write whatever you want.

\SlideTitle {The second slide}
Continue writing.
% \externalfigure[logo.png][width=3cm,frame=off] % How to include a logo?
\stoptext

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: context
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% TeX-engine: luatex
%%% End:
```

Comment: I am  one of the co-authors of simpleslides (but I am not longer a current maintainer). The module does not provide any mechanism for placing a logo. So, using layers to place the logo is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not the most automated solution, but as you can still use any valid ConTeXt solution I would suggest layers. Please note that in the current example you have to do manual positioning.

[image: slides]

```
\usemodule[visualcounter]
\usemodule[simpleslides][style=Sunrise] 
\setupTitle
  [ title={Simple Slides?},
   author={Hirwanto},
     date={6 Januari 2013},
  ]



\setupvisualcounter
  [simpleslides:squarescounter]
  [
   distance={(\the\dimexpr\visualcounterparameter{maxwidth})/last_counter - width},
  ]

\definelayer[logo][state=repeat]
\setlayer[logo][x=\dimexpr(\paperwidth-4cm)\relax,y=8.75cm]{\externalfigure[example-image.png][width=3cm,frame=off]}

\setupSlideTitle[after={\placelayer[logo]}]

\starttext

\placeTitle

\SlideTitle {The first slide}

Write whatever you want.

\SlideTitle {The second slide}
Continue writing.
\stoptext
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable idea of using layers. To me this is a satisfactory solution, I still don't realize the potential power of context in doing it better than this. Please allow me to wait for other possible answers before accepting it as the answer to this question.

Comment: @doctorate I'm pretty sure that there is a better solution (at least more automated placement), so I'm also interested in a solution by the experts :)

Comment: Always terminate `\dimexpr` with `\relax`.

Comment: @HenriMenke Good point, thanks. I've edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

Using Texnician's solution, you can write your own module like

```
\startmodule myslidesetup
\setupvisualcounter
  [simpleslides:squarescounter]
  [
   distance={(\the\dimexpr\visualcounterparameter{maxwidth})/last_counter - width},
  ]

\definelayer[logo][state=repeat]
\setlayer[logo][x=\dimexpr(\paperwidth-4cm),y=8.75cm]{\externalfigure[example-image.png][width=3cm,frame=off]}

\setupSlideTitle[after={\placelayer[logo]}]
\stopmodule
```

and save it in a file `t-myslidesetup.tex` that can be in the same directory (or a parent)

Then you can use your setup like this :

```
\usemodule[visualcounter]
\usemodule[simpleslides][style=Sunrise] 
\usemodule[myslidesetup]

\setupTitle
  [ title={Simple Slides?},
   author={Hirwanto},
     date={6 Januari 2013},
  ]

\starttext

\placeTitle

\SlideTitle {The first slide}

Write whatever you want.

\SlideTitle {The second slide}
Continue writing.
\stoptext
```

You can also include the two calls

```
\usemodule[visualcounter]
\usemodule[simpleslides][style=Sunrise]
```

in your own module (in the very beginning). Everything you write in your own module will override default setups so you don't have to tweak the original file and it is better if you want to share (no need to find, share and replace the modified system files).

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for the input I am aware of a similar mechanism explained in the documentation file of `simpleslides` module, page 35 `Using your own styles`, just `\usemodule[simpleslides][style=myslidesetup]` would be enough if you would copy the original `s-simpleslides-Sunrise.tex` to your working dir and rename it to e.g. `s-myslidesetup` and of course adapt your changes there, it will automatically be picked up as a module. Try it for yourself.

Comment: by the way as a naming rule, I'd prefer names which indicate which style I copied from, e.g. `s-mysunrise.tex` instead of giving a general name like `s-myslidesetup.tex` kind of thing.